# Keep only lines in String which contain numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, textbox

I have tried couple of regular expressions but have not been able to come up with one that works correctly. I have string with lines and I want to keep the lines which contains numbers.

```
Current String
-----------------

Dog

Cat

Cat 1

Dog 22
```

Once processed the expected result is:

```
Filtered String
-----------------
Cat 1

Dog 22
```

Comment: So you need just a regex that checks that a string contains at least one digit (0-9)?

Comment: Matching a single digit (`\d`) will do. [You don't need regex though](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Andrey Nasonov yes and allows new space and newlines

Comment: @ndn Thanks for the comment, It returns a bool how can I get the filtered results ?

Comment: @AlstonAntony, just [select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) the lines, which have a digit.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex solution? And is the input a single string with newlines, or a collection of strings?

Comment: @SWeko it doesn't have to be regex thats what I tried to do and it's a single string with newlines in it

Comment: @AlstonAntony, [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) it to get a collection.

Comment: @ndn can you please give sample answer I am still not clear on your approach

Comment: @AlstonAntony, Eren's answer is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.Split('\n').Where(s => s.Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c)));
```

This splits the string by newline ('\n') characters, and for each "line", it finds the ones that have *at least one* character that is a digit.